# Oracle floating calculation

Tags: oracle, precision

I am performing the following Oracle selects:

1. `Select 1 / 48 * 24 * 60 From Dual`

> result: 29.99999999999999999999999999999999999995

2. `Select 1 / 48 * 60 * 24 From Dual`

> result: 30

3. `Select 1 / 48 * (60 * 24) From Dual`

> result: 29.99999999999999999999999999999999999995

The interesting thing here is that if I multiply  `1 / 48 * 24` the returned result is 0.499999999999... instead of 0.5. This leads to 29.999 result.

Why is this result returned? What should I do in order to avoid such calculations that seem to be different than expected?

Comment: **[What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)**

Comment: (1/a) * b * c = (b*c)/a, which is less likely to fall foul of floating-point limitations, but if you mean 30 then write 30 and put in a comment about where it comes from.